# Chromecast error message "Unable to create service com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService"

Tags: android, chromecast

I am trying to build an android application with chromecast.

I use MediaRouter to select chromecast devices but there are some error messages when I select and unselect many times.

For example, I select chromecast device, load media, play media then unselect. When I try to load the media at 4th or 5th, the error message show up.

There is the error message.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.kevin.chromecasttest, PID: 1066
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder ani.asBinder()' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2909)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:150)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5444)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:746)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder ani.asBinder()' on a null object reference
     at anl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:47)
     at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.internal.CastDynamiteModuleImpl.newMediaNotificationServiceImpl(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:72)
     at aap.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:121)
     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzog.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.MediaNotificationService.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2899)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:150) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5444) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:746) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Please open a ticket on our issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list) and include the stack trace, steps, etc. If you can reproduce this with the official CastVideos-android sample app, that would make it easier.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will try to reproduce this with the official sample app.